# Can't ping host in OpenVPN Site-to-Site VPN

Tags: openvpn, pfsense, site-to-site-vpn

My logs say that a connection has been established but I cant ping the host.

Here are my logs.

### Firewall 1 Logs:

```
May 24 10:42:57 openvpn[9163]: /etc/rc.filter_configure tun0 1500 1544 10.0.8.1 10.0.8.2 init  
May 24 10:42:57 openvpn[9163]: SIGTERM[hard,] received, process exiting  
May 24 10:42:59 openvpn[9742]: OpenVPN 2.0.6 i386-portbld-freebsd7.2 [SSL] [LZO] built on Dec 4 2009  
May 24 10:42:59 openvpn[9742]: WARNING: file '/var/etc/openvpn_server0.key' is group or others accessible  
May 24 10:42:59 openvpn[9742]: gw 112.202.0.1  
May 24 10:42:59 openvpn[9742]: TUN/TAP device /dev/tun0 opened  
May 24 10:42:59 openvpn[9742]: /sbin/ifconfig tun0 10.0.8.1 10.0.8.2 mtu 1500 netmask 255.255.255.255 up  
May 24 10:42:59 openvpn[9742]: /etc/rc.filter_configure tun0 1500 1544 10.0.8.1 10.0.8.2 init  
May 24 10:43:00 openvpn[9757]: Listening for incoming TCP connection on [undef]:1194  
May 24 10:43:00 openvpn[9757]: TCPv4_SERVER link local (bound): [undef]:1194  
May 24 10:43:00 openvpn[9757]: TCPv4_SERVER link remote: [undef]  
May 24 10:43:00 openvpn[9757]: Initialization Sequence Completed  
May 24 10:43:02 openvpn[9757]: Re-using SSL/TLS context  
May 24 10:43:02 openvpn[9757]: LZO compression initialized  
May 24 10:43:02 openvpn[9757]: TCP connection established with 119.93.150.4:47750  
May 24 10:43:02 openvpn[9757]: TCPv4_SERVER link local: [undef]  
May 24 10:43:02 openvpn[9757]: TCPv4_SERVER link remote: 119.93.150.4:47750  
May 24 10:43:06 openvpn[9757]: 119.93.150.4:47750 [client] Peer Connection Initiated with 119.93.150.4:47750
```

### Firewall 2 Logs:

```
May 24 10:42:57 openvpn[7489]: Connection reset, restarting [0]  
May 24 10:42:57 openvpn[7489]: SIGUSR1[soft,connection-reset] received, process restarting  
May 24 10:43:02 openvpn[7489]: WARNING: No server certificate verification method has been enabled. See http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm for more info.  
May 24 10:43:02 openvpn[7489]: Re-using SSL/TLS context  
May 24 10:43:02 openvpn[7489]: LZO compression initialized  
May 24 10:43:02 openvpn[7489]: Attempting to establish TCP connection with 112.202.103.45:1194  
May 24 10:43:02 openvpn[7489]: TCP connection established with 112.202.103.45:1194  
May 24 10:43:02 openvpn[7489]: TCPv4_CLIENT link local: [undef]  
May 24 10:43:02 openvpn[7489]: TCPv4_CLIENT link remote: 112.202.103.45:1194  
May 24 10:43:06 openvpn[7489]: [server] Peer Connection Initiated with 112.202.103.45:1194  
May 24 10:43:08 openvpn[7489]: Options error: Unrecognized option or missing parameter(s) in [PUSH-OPTIONS]:1: 112.202.103.45 (2.0.6)  
May 24 10:43:08 openvpn[7489]: Preserving previous TUN/TAP instance: tun0  
May 24 10:43:08 openvpn[7489]: Initialization Sequence Completed
```

What could the problem be?

Answer (score 2):

It appears that even though you seem to have a "push" option in the config file for firewall2, there is a syntactical problem with it:

```
May 24 10:43:08 openvpn[7489]: Options error: Unrecognized option or missing parameter(s) in [PUSH-OPTIONS]:1: 112.202.103.45 (2.0.6)
```

Once this is fixed, you should have routing through the tunnel, which will give firewall2 access to machines on the other end of the tunnel.

Comment: how about this warning? openvpn[341]: WARNING: No server certificate verification method has been enabled. See http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm for more info.

Comment: Well, what about it? It's a warning. If you are not particularly concerned about this, then ignore it. If you are concerned, follow the instructions in the HowTo.

Answer (score 0):

We had this same problem using OpenVPN. The fix we found was that OpenVPN must alway be ran as an administrator. I know it sounds ridiculous, but it works.

Comment: Windows Vista and 7 won't let a program add routes unless it's run as administrator, the VPN itself will work just fine but the route addition fails so most of the VPN won't work. Not ridiculous really, just the way Windows works. But that doesn't apply to site to site connections (unless one end is running on Windows which doesn't appear to be the case here).

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the push, which probably isn't enough to break the connection, the logs look normal. You're likely missing a route, or have the route wrong, on one or both ends.